# Aggregate and count the status in field using FME Workbench

Tags: aggregate, geospatial, spatial, fme

I have two layers point and a polygon, I wanted to have the aggregate of a column name "Progress" with its respective polygon name and polygon id. The progress field in the point layer has the values namely 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 . The count is the total number of points inside the polygon.

The result should be like this

| count | Name | PolygonID | Progress 1 | Progress 2 | progress 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54 | Lester | 25 | 23 | 12 | 19 |
| 80 | Laspringe | 456 | 40 | 10 | 30 |
| 75 | Marius | 256 | 25 | 30 | 20 |

I have currently done this process in FME

[image]

The result is

[image]

How to change the workbench to attain the desired result. Any leads will be helpful. Thank you.